# Power BI - Get JWT Token from Auth API

Tags: jwt, powerbi, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed an API that requires JWT access tokens which contain a user's claims and must be submitted as the Authorization header to get any data. It works perfectly well when making requests via Postman or through a .NET HTTP Client and it is pretty standard implementation.

Our business would now like to connect to the data through our APIs using Power BI. We don't have much experience with it but I understand the fundamentals. Have wateched some PluralSight videos etc to familiarize myself. What I'm really having problems with is actually getting the token for use in the queries.

I've googled around and found https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Pull-data-from-RESTful-API-with-token-authentication/td-p/80531 the last answer of which seems to be what I'm looking for.

I have this query:

```
let

GetJson = Web.Contents("https://mydomain.co.uk/api/token",
[
Headers = [#"Accept"="application/json",
#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
Content = Text.ToBinary("grant_type=password&username=me&password=My_Pass11")
]
),
FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(FormatAsJson),
#"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value", {"Data"}, {"Data"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Data", {"access_token", "expires_in", "culture", "resourceList", "roles", "applicationId", "userCurrency", "userDateFormat", "userProductWeight", "roleNames"}, {"access_token", "expires_in", "culture", "resourceList", "roles", "applicationId", "userCurrency", "userDateFormat", "userProductWeight", "roleNames"}),
access_token = #"Expanded Data"{0}[access_token]
in
access_token
```

Makes sense to why that would work, but when I close the query editor, Power BI tries to connect and shows the error "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again."
If I click the Edit Credentials button, I go to web query settings for the request, which isn't really going to help as it's a HTTP Post without Auth (so is set to Anonymous). Any thoughts to how to sort this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the query to this (using Username and Password parameters now):

```
let

GetJson = Web.Contents("https://mydomain.co.uk/api/token",
[
Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
Content = Text.ToBinary("grant_type=password&username=" &Username&"&password="&Password&"&clienttype=User")
]
),
FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(FormatAsJson),
access_token = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Value]
in
access_token
```

Problem now solved. Now I just need to work out how to use access_token in another query...